# Question regarding perfect matchings in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, matching-theory

I have a connected, bridgeless graph with 72 vertices of degree 3 and 2 vertices of degree 2. Is there a way that I can prove that this graph has a perfect matching?

From the graph I can see there is a perfect matching, but I would like to obtain it by a proof without getting from the drawing. (Even by thinking of a general case, like a connected, bridgeless graph has k number of vertices of degree 3, where k is even and 2 vertices of degree 2. Then can we prove that it has a perfect matching?)

Please help me with this question.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Attached below is the mentioned graph. Please consider that the point marked as 52, enclosed in a square is not a part of the graph. Is there any suggestion to prove that this graph is bridgeless (if I do not know its bridgeless)?

[image]

Comment: How do you manage to draw the graph?

Comment: @mathpadawan This is actually from a Cayley graph of a semidirect product of two finite groups. I drew that graph using points obtained in GAP and I am experimenting by deleting vertices, so I ended up with above mentioned graph :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two degree 2 vertices are not connected, connect them by an edge and apply Peterson's theorem and use the fact that you can pick any edge and there will be a perfect matching without that edge.  Else, say the edge connecting them is $uv$, subdivide it and add a new vertex $S$ as in the following picture. So apply Peterson on the resulting graph with $SW$ removed!?

[image]

Comment: Yes please write the full solution as well @mathpadawan Thank you very much

Comment: The two degree two vertices are connected in the graph @mathpadawan I checked now. What if I add another edge between those two vertices (then it will be a multigraph with each vertex having degree 3, right?). Then also can I apply Peterson theorem? The graph is bridgeless, from the diagram I can see, but I am glad if an approach can be suggested to prove that it is bridgeless

Comment: please help me in this question. Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Oh! I think I got it: say the edge connecting the two degree 2 vertices is uv. subdivide uv into uwv and then add new vertex s and add edge sw, su,sv. Now apply Peterson on the resulting graph where we remove sw! How is that?

Comment: Somebody please comments, See if the proof is correct!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thank you very much @mathpadawan When we are using Peterson's theorem without the edge $sw$  the vertex $s$ will have degree 2, then is it possible to explain how to proceed?

Comment: And I edited the question including a figure of the graph. Is it possible to suggest an approach or guide me to prove that the above graph is bridgeless ? Thanks a lot @mathpadawan  :) :)

Comment: Ah, you are right, that doesn't work.... Damn I hope someone give a solution